# Chrome is stretching the height of my max-width image

Tags: image-scaling, css

I'm having trouble with setting the max-width of my images in a CMS I'm using. In Chrome (untested in other browsers yet), setting a max-width stretches the height of the image I insert -  see here: http://www.literarykitchen.co.uk/events/testspace/

This is the code I'm using:

```
#content .pagebanner img { max-width:490px; }
```

Is there any reason why it's stretching like that? I thought maxwidth meant images scale in proportion?

Thanks

Osu

Comment: Found the answer through a little trial and error - you need to set height to 'auto': `#content .pagebanner img { max-width:490px; height:auto; }`

Comment: This solution does not work for me in Chrome. :(

Comment: @mcandre Odd; it does for me. Chrome 22.0.1..etc....

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, My image gallery was dynamic and all the images were different sizes uploaded by the user. So I had to make sure this worked. What solved it for me was to set the `max-width:` , the `max-height:` , `height:` , and `width:` otherwise it didn't work for me.

**Example:**

```
#image-container-div img {
    max-width: 490px;
    max-height: 490px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer as it helped in a few spots.

While making our site Mobilegeddon ready, I discovered that tweaking the width setting above to 100% gives me the best of all solutions:

`#image-container-div img {
    max-width: 490px;
    max-height: 490px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 2):

For those of you with this issue using `display: flex` on the parent element, your issue may be that you need to set `align-items` on the parent element to something other than the default of `stretch`, e.g. `align-items: flex-start`.